# A-Frame: rayOrigin cursor and mouse at same time

Tags: cursor, mouse, aframe

I've implemented events like in this example:
https://aframe-event-set-component.glitch.me/

These events now ether listen to my cursor OR to my mouse.
How can i combine both methods in one application so that the events can be triggered by mouse and cursor? Just like here: 
https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-mouse-cursor-component (not supported by the latest A-Frame any more)

Can i write something like `cursor="rayOrigin: mouse && cursor"`?

Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

As for the `click` event: it seems to be working with two `cursor` components: one in the `a-scene`, and one in the camera:

```
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
  <a-camera position="0 1.6 0">
    <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500" position="0 0 -1" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03" material="color: black; shader: flat">
    </a-entity>
  </a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

Check it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6p0r36bL/4/).

---

On the other hand the `a-scene`s cursor seems to mess up the other [events](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/cursor.html#events).
You could file an [issue](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues), or create a component, which removes the mouse `cursor` when the `enter-vr` event is emitted.

```
...
this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener("enter-vr", function() {
  this.el.removeAttribute("cursor")
})
this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener("exit-vr", function() {
  this.el.setAttrubute("cursor", "rayOrigin", "mouse")
})
```