# a-scene cursor breaks raycaster

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am trying to setup having fuse to trigger hover animations, whilst still having the ability to click/tap on items in the environment.

Adding `<a-cursor position="0 0 -0.25"></a-cursor>` as a child of my camera gives the ring cursor on-screen and allows the hover mouseenter/mouseleave eventListeners to fire as expected.

I then add `cursor="rayOrigin:mouse;"` to a-scene, so that I'm able to click on objects in the scene, but this breaks the hover animations.

For the hover animations I have a plane which is invisible but in front of the animating object that has the mouseenter/mouseleave eventListeners.  However, when the cursor has both the plane and object behind in the raycast mouseleave is called.  This doesn't happen if `cursor="rayOrigin:mouse;"` is ommitted.

Glitch here --> https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/49af29f1-557a-4976-bc2b-f89fce5e3ad6

Comment: Without code to run and debug it will be hard to help. I recommend sharing simple code that illustrates the question with https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: Hey Diego - I've added a glitch showing the problem - like I said if you remove cursor="rayOrigin:mouse;" it works as expected, but then I can't click on objects in the scene

Comment: If there's a way to limit the raycaster to focus on the first intersected mesh I think that may help??

Comment: You could make sure only one `cursor` is active at a time - no need to have two mouses :) Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321064/a-frame-rayorigin-cursor-and-mouse-at-same-time).

Comment: The answer below gets this working as expected on mobile devices, but I'm still seeing strange behaviour on desktop.  For instance if I click the mouse off to one side it registers a click at the fuse cursors position.  Any way to apply whatever is happening on mobile to the desktop version? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<a-cursor>` interferes with the scene's cursor

```
<a-scene cursor="...">
  <a-camera>
    <a-cursor>
    </a-cursor>
```

because the `raycaster` created by `<a-cursor>` emits events (upon intersection, and clearance) which bubble up and gets captured by the `<a-scene>`s cursor. Exactly by [these two listeners](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v1.0.0/src/components/cursor.js#L130-L131).

To prevent them from interfering, you can get rid of the parent-child relation between the two:

```
<a-camera>
  <a-cursor>
  </a-cursor>
</a-camera>
<a-entity cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"></a-entity>
```

Check it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mugt4rds/1/)

---

Another way would be dynamically adding / removing one of the cursors, so that only the 'intended' one is working at a time.

Comment: it probably should be changed so that the `cursor` reacts only to the `raycaster` it created

Comment: I owe you serious amounts of beer! Thanks again for your expertise